# Data not being added to the database SQLITE

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

I was trying to insert data on an SQLITE database but it is not there when I open the database.

I am trying to do an application that is able to store data on a database. But when I try to add data, it doesn't get added to the table. Here's the code for the database helper and for the activity in which I call the insert data function:

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Channels.db" ;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Channels_table" ;
public static final String COL_1 = "Channel_number" ;
public static final String COL_2 = "Channel_name" ;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null , 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (Channel_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , Channel_name TEXT )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(int c_number , String c_name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1 , c_number);
    contentValues.put(COL_2 , c_name);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null , contentValues);

    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

public class Add_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseHelper db;

EditText channel_name , channel_number ;
Button Add_button;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_view);

    channel_name = findViewById(R.id.channel_name_textview);
    channel_number = findViewById(R.id.channel_number_textview);
    Add_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Button_tapped();

}

public void Button_tapped(){
    Add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(channel_name.getText().toString().isEmpty() || channel_number.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(Add_Activity.this , getText(R.string.empty_fields) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (Integer.parseInt(channel_number.getText().toString()) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(channel_number.getText().toString()) > 84){
                Toast.makeText(Add_Activity.this , getText(R.string.invalid_channel_numb) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                channel_number.setText("");
            }
            else {
                boolean insertdata = db.insertData(Integer.parseInt(channel_number.getText().toString()) , channel_name.getText().toString());

                if (insertdata){
                    Toast.makeText(Add_Activity.this , getText(R.string.successfull_insertion) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(Add_Activity.this , getText(R.string.unsuccessfull_insertion) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                channel_number.setText("");
                channel_name.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

When I tap the button, I get the toast for the unsuccessful insertion and the data is not being inserted into the database. What I need is to be able to see the successful insertion toast and to find the data in the database.

Comment: what are the values you're trying to insert? Also, did you make sure that the sqlite file was created?

Comment: @AlanDeep i am trying to insert the channel number which would be an integer and the channel name which would be a string. And yes, the database file is being created and i was able to find it.

Comment: I assume that you did not try to add a duplicate primary key, try this constructor:
`public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context,@Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory){
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, 1);
}`

Comment: @AlanDeep no i did not enter any duplicate to any values. And i already tried to use this constructor but i had problems with the parameters and decided to only keep the context like i was advised

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code. Check your string resources, maybe they are being inserted but you're getting a logical error "unsuccessful" why it's "successful"

Comment: I mean check the value of `R.string.unsuccessfull_insertion`, maybe it's `=` to successful

Comment: @AlanDeep i think that the string ressources are right because when i tap the button i get the unsuccessful message and i don't see the data in the database

Comment: search in your logcat for SQLiteException you should find an error like INSERT INTO ....... (?,?)

Comment: @AlanDeep i tried again now and i got an error saying Error inserting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COL_2 + " TEXT )");
```

instead of

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (Channel_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , Channel_name TEXT )");
```

Comment: The table is created but the data is not being added to it

Comment: sqlite in android is sensitive. you have to do what i'm telling you. Especially this old sqlite way.

Comment: @Gabriel Chammas make the changes that are proposed in this answer, then uninstall the app from the device and finally rerun.

Comment: @AlanDeep I tried to do this change but it still did not work. I tried adding a new entry to the database, I got the successful message but I am not able to see the new entry in the database still.

Comment: @AlanDeep I think that I found my problem. It was with the way I opened the database file to check its contents. It seems that I need to save the database file each time I make a new entry to see the new entry in the database. Thank you for helping me